# Sum Up rows with the same name and value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have a table which looks like that:

[image]

I want to sum up all the values which have the same name string and the same date, so that I get such a table:

[image]

I have to say that I do not know how such a thing could be implemented. I tried something like an `if...else` structure, but what I am missing is the checking part of the other rows. Any suggestion how to implement such a problem?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [SUMIFS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx) in `E2` and drag it down:

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$10,$A$2:$A$10,A2,$B$2:$B$10,B2)
```